# Getting rownames from hclust() function in R using the hclust 'order' parameter

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

Using the mtcars data set as an example, I am trying to extract the ordered row names from a dendrogram.

The code below performances a clustering analysis, extracts the ordered indices from the dendrogram, and draws the diagram. hc$order gives just the indices. How do I extract the ordered labels shown on the dendrogram image below?

```
    hc <- hclust(dist(mtcars))
    hc$order
    dd <- as.dendrogram(hc)
    order.dendrogram(dd)
```

mtcars dendrogram output [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6je9Z.png)

Comment: try: `rownames(mtcars[hc$order,])`

Comment: This worked - thanks!